# Using OSGi to attach JMenuItems to GUI

Tags: java, swing, osgi, apache-felix

I have created an application and now I want it to make a plugin ready. I have decided to use Apache Felix and after reading tutorial, I am not sure, whether it was a choice that I wanted to.

I want to change my application, so that it loads at the beginning Bundles from /plugins folder and adds every Bundle as a JMenuItem to JMenu. I could have done it using ClassLoader, but I thought OSGi was exactly what I wanted, but then I encountered some problems:

- there is a command line for OSGi, but I need it to be implemented in my application, without any user interaction, hard code its default behaviour in code.
- there is behaviour of a Bundle ( `start()` and `stop()` methods inherited from `org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator`) that Bundle invokes at the beginning, but I actually want my application, to do something with a Bundle, not a Bundle to do something with an application.

So could you tell me, whether it is possible to make it using OSGi (etc. Apache Felix) or should I implement it using ClassLoader and then explicitly convert a .jar plugin's Main Class to JMenuItem and add it to my JMenu (it is worse, because it doesn't support dynamic change of application and doesn't give me a chance to learn OSGi).

EDIT: I am thinking about sth like: http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/plugable-swing-a-hello-world-osgi-example/ , but I cannot find any tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you create a menu item for every bundle that exists in the view? That doesn't really make sense.

You /could/ do it by creating your GUI app, and then in the start() method, persist the context and then use that to query a list of all bundles in the system. You would probably want to do that on demand when your menu was shown (so you see a current list).

However, you're really thinking in the wrong direction. What you want to do is look for /services/. When a service comes in, you use that service to populate your menu item. That way, you can have multiple services per bundle and the services can have some form of interaction.

Neil Bartlett and myself did a talk on exactly this approach for a Swing-based application (though using registered Action objects). The demo and presentation are still available from this location:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/files/jsig/

Note that this was done at the time of OSGi v4, so you might find the install fails with a mismatched version of the import framework. If so, crack open the file and ensure that it doesn't say `Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3.0,1.4.0)"` or some such - get rid of the version numbers and it should still run fine today.

Comment: +1 to Alex's answer. To address a few more points in the original question; the command line in OSGi is entirely optional, if you don't want it then don't use it. BundleActivators are also entirely optional. Finally, the design primitive you want to use is an **OSGi Service**. Please read about them! As Alex says, it doesn't make sense to add a bundle to a menu (what would happen when you click it??)

Comment: I have problems with this page, the links are now working, do you have those materials somewhere else?

Comment: Please try again, when I load it it is fine.

Comment: Sorry, i reply so late. It works fine, but I don't want to use Knoplerfish's console. I want it all to be embedded in my application, so when you run an application (as a .jar file most probably) the OSGi console doesn't show up. But I stucked, because all of the examples shows working Bundles using OSGi Destop instead of showing nothing.

Comment: There is nothing that forces you to use Knopflerfish's console, and I'm not sure why you would think that is the case.

Comment: Well, I simply don't know how to use OSGi without this console, I tried to call main() method of a Knopflerfish's Main class, tried other magic things and I just don't get it, how to make an app without a console, I even cannot find a supportive documentation.
In a nutshell, I don't know how to implement main() of my application.

Comment: Your application shouldn't implement a main(). Start up the OSGi runtime with your bundle installed, and then in your bundle have a BundleActivator to perform startup specifics that you need. See http://wiki.osgi.org/BundleActivator for information about the BundleActivator class.